# Calling Routines in Subclasses

Tags: swift

I have a user-defined class Map, with one instance map. map contains a two-dimensional array of user-defined objects called squares, of type Grid. The Grid class contains a variable called contains, which contains one object of many possible user-defined classes. From the Grid module, I am trying to call a function in a user-defined class called Bug.

What is the proper syntax for doing this?

```
//within Class Grid

func GenerateImage() -> Int{

        if self.containType == 1{
            return self.contains.DisplayBug()
        }else if self.containType == 2{
            return 13
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }

//within class Bug

func DisplayBug() -> Int{
    if self.male == false{
        return self.direction
    }else{
        if self.appearance == 1{
            switch self.direction{
            case 1:
                return 5
            case 2:
                return 6
            case 3:
                return 7
            case 4:
                return 8
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }else if self.appearance == 2{
            switch self.direction{
            case 1:
                return 9
            case 2:
                return 10
            case 3:
                return 11
            case 4:
                return 12
            default:
                return 0
            }
        }else{
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your method alternatively... `func displayBug() -> Int {
    if !male {
        return direction
    } else {
        if 1...2 ~= appearance {
            return direction + (4 * appearance)
        } else { return 0 }
    }
}`

Comment: Or you can make your methods just computed properties

Answer (score 0):

I've took the liberty to make an example structure of the classes that you have, since you did not provide the implementation of those classes:

```
class Grid {
    let contains: SomeProtocol

    init(contains: SomeProtocol) {
        self.contains = contains
    }
}

class Map {
    let squares: [[Grid]]

    init(squares: [[Grid]]) {
        self.squares = squares
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `contains` property is of type SomeProtocol, which is defined like so:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    func displayBug()
}
```

Next come the classes that implement this protocol (this is just an example to illustrate that the implementation of the `displayBug` method may vary):

```
class Bug: SomeProtocol {
    func displayBug() {
        print("called from Bug")
    }
}
class Foo: SomeProtocol {
    func displayBug() {
        print("called from Foo")
    }
}
class Bar: SomeProtocol {
    func displayBug() {
        print("called from Bar")
    }
}
class Buz: SomeProtocol {
    func displayBug() {
        print("called from Buz")
    }
}
```

Now that the hierarchy is in place, we can test it:

```
let map = Map(squares: [
    [
        Grid(contains: Bug()),
        Grid(contains: Foo())
    ],
    [
        Grid(contains: Bar()),
        Grid(contains: Buz())
    ]
])

for gridArray in map.squares {
    for grid in gridArray {
        grid.contains.displayBug()
    }
}
```

> called from Bug
>
> called from Foo
>
> called from Bar
>
> called from Buz